# want to make web site using Java, should i implement struts?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, struts

I want to make discussion form kind of website using java, should i just make it using JSP- Servlet - Java code or should i use some framework like struts ...

I am new to Java, but i have sufficient exposure of programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you're trying to achieve.

As far as frameworks go I would recommend checking out Spring over Struts (Although they can be used together, Spring has an equivalent Spring-MVC).

But Spring might be a bit involved for a Java newbie, even if you do have other language experience. Maybe experiment with JSPs/servlet first and check out Spring once you're comfortable with them (I recommend Spring in Action for reading material)

... Also, if we're talking a bit more outside the box (I see someone else mentioned Scala/Lift), another alternative would be Groovy on Grails. This is based on Spring, and owned by SpringSource, but is much more fun/quick to develop with. Plus if your previous experience happens to be with dynamic langs such as Python/Ruby, Groovy would be worth checking out.

Comment: +1 But I would add, even if you start with just a JSP/servlet approach then first read about the Model, View, Controller (MVC) design pattern, and don't just put all your application logic within the JSP files themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) too. I have watched their demo and it's programming model looks promising to me.

Comment: +1 for Play Framework, with scala + scalate plugins it's perfect

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Struts then make sure to use Struts 2.  I would not recommend anyone write a new app in Struts 1 as it is very verbose and requires lots of configuration.  However, Struts 2 is pretty awesome.  I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/struts-2-tutorial-getting-started/) on it if that's the route you'd like to go.

Comment: +1 for your tutorial, however I'm more interested in Apache Tapestry 5 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a basic understanding of servlet API, but you will most probably prefer to use some web framework built upon it. Struts is just one of them, popular and simple though a little old; there are many others

To name some: Struts, Spring-MVC, Stripes, Struts2, Wicket, JSF, Tapestry, GWT... an many others.
(Struts2 is not a new version of Struts, it's rather a new version of Webworks).

Unfortunately none of them is a clear winner.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider Scala with Lift. I am building my next site in this and it is a very promising, light weight, less verbose, Java language.

Comment: I think you mean "JVM language"?

Answer (score 0):

You *WILL* need to understand servlets and what you can do with them regardless what, as all modern Java-based web platforms build on top of that.

The Sun tutorial for servlets is at http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether to use a framework at all or just use plain JSP-Servlet-Java I'd say that as long as you have a grasp of the language and Servlet API as other have said, the extra effort to learn a framework on top of that is well worth it in the long run. If you don't use a framework you eventually find that either a lot of your code becomes tedious, repetitive 'plumbing' or that you've essentially created your own framework anyway. Creating frameworks can be fun but if you have a job to do with a deadline, using an existing one saves a huge amount of time and effort.